# Return Value of 3rd qudrant

Tags: r

Is there a way to return the value of the `3rd Qu.` that comes up when you do the summary of a vector?

For example:

```
summary(data$attribute)
```

Returns:

```
Min.  1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 

0.0002012 0.0218800 0.0454300 0.0707100 0.0961500 0.4845000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `quantile` and specify the probability to be 0.75:

```
quantile(1:10, probs = 0.75)
# 75% 
#7.75
```

If you want to remove the name attribute:

```
quantile(1:10, probs = 0.75, names = FALSE)
#7.75
```

---

Comment: Is there a way to just get the output to be 7.75 without the 75% text?

Comment: You can use it basically as `7.75` and ignore 75% since it is just a name attribute of the numeric. For example, `quantile(1:10, 0.75) + 1` gives: `75% 8.75`. However if you indeed want to remove the name attribute, you can do `as.numeric(quantile(1:10, 0.75))` or `unname(quantile(1:10, 0.75))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can access elements of the `summary` by index:

```
summary(1:10)
# Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
# 1.00    3.25    5.50    5.50    7.75   10.00

summary(1:10)[5]
# 3rd Qu.
#   7.75
```

Or by name:

```
summary(1:10)["3rd Qu."]
# 3rd Qu. 
#   7.75
```

We can use `unname()` to drop names:

```
unname(summary(1:10)[5])
# [1] 7.75
```

Comment: Is there a way to just get the value, without the 3rd Qu. Text?